# Can webpack keep child module's path while exporting?

Tags: webpack

Suppose I have a project,which structure is like this

```
projectFolder
--index.html
--img
--js
--childMod
    --modA
        --index.html
        --img
        --js
```

In normal config for webpack multiple pages.all images include images in child module will be place into the same folder,like this

```
buildFolder
--index.html
--modA.html
--allImgs
--bundle.js
--modA.bundle.js
```

I want webpack keep the project structure,like this

```
buildFolder
--index.html
--imgs
--bundle.js
--childMod
    --childModImgs
    --modA.html
    --modA.bundle.js
```

My target is,webpack can recognize the resource's path,if it is inside childMod,then they will be output and placed in childMod's folder,not all together in one folder.
How to make it?

Answer (score 0):

From [this Github comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/395#issuecomment-51176561), yes you can do it for the file loader:

```
file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=/the/root/path
```

This copies the file `/the/root/path/dir/file.png` to `/output-directory/dir/file.png.`

In a Webpack config it might look like:

```
  { test: \.png$/, loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=/the/root/path" },
```

For assets like CSS and Javascript that are passed through other loaders that bundle and minify the data, no, there's no way to do this. It wouldn't make sense because the Javascript files can come from various folders across the project.

Comment: thanks,but the loader's  test can't filter the path,only the filename.

so,how do i make it know what asset under specify path,and output going to the same path?