# Webpack compiling one-to-one build directory with source directory

Tags: reactjs, sass, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

1. Is there a way to compile all files in the source directory to a
   build directory that maintains the same directory structure?
2. Can I do the above without manually specifying multiple entry points to the `webpack.config.js` file every time I add a new component?

Will I need Gulp to accomplish this? I've successfully done this with Grunt + Browserify. Grunt has a prop called `expand: true` which does this for me easily.

For example, I want to compile the following:

```
src
 |-- app
     |-- index.html
     |-- index.jsx
     |-- routes.jsx
     |-- components
             |-- Home
                  |-- home.jsx
                  |-- home.scss
             |-- About
                  |-- about.jsx
                  |-- about.scss
     |-- common
             |-- Dropdown
                  |-- dropdown.jsx
                  |-- dropdown.scss
```

to:

```
build
 |-- app
     |-- index.html
     |-- index.js
     |-- routes.js
     |-- components
             |-- Home
                  |-- home.js
                  |-- home.css
             |-- About
                  |-- about.js
                  |-- about.css
     |-- common
             |-- Dropdown
                  |-- dropdown.js
                  |-- dropdown.css
```

Comment: This wouldn't really make sense because webpack concatenates CSS and JS into bundled files.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303083/can-webpack-keep-child-modules-path-while-exporting

Comment: In the case of CSS, what if I set `body {background: red}` in `home.scss` and body `{background: blue}` in `about.scss`. If they are concatenated as one file, then in both pages the last style for the same selector will be used on both the `home` and `about` webpages. How do I get them to be loaded separately depending on the current page?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Please either edit this question to demonstrate your specific problem, or close this and open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack is not intended to be a source to source transformation utility. So it is not trivial do something like compile all sass files in a folder to equivalent css files. If this is really what you want you want you can just write an npm script that does that using node-sass [command line interface](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface).

If you really need to use webpack to do this, then you can build programmatically build the entries using [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) matching. Webpack configuration is just javascript, you can use any logic to build up the configuration object.

The "webpack way" is to have an entry point and require what you need from javascript files.

Now to address your specific concern about css rules being overriden, `style-loader` provides you the ability to dispose off injected stylesheets through a [reference counted api](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader#reference-counted-api).

```
var style = require("style/useable!css!./home.css");
style.use(); 
style.unuse(); // when you navigate away from the page.
```